# Inserting lines of text between different lines of text

Tags: batch-file, cmd, insert, windows-7-x64

I want to insert lines of text between different lines of text, For example:

I am Running on Windows 7 x64.

I have a file called Lines2Insert.txt, this file contains thousands of lines of text that look like the following:

```
WRAITH_CAPITALBATTLESHIP                 
WRAITH_CAPITALCARRIER             
WRAITH_CAPITALCOLONY                                                               
WRAITH_CAPITALSIEGE              
WRAITH_CAPITALSUPPORT             
WRAITH_CAPITALTRANSPORT  
WRAITH_CRUISERANTIMODULE
```

I want to insert each line of text twice between this line of text which is on a different file which looks like this.

```
StringInfo  
    ID "IDS_(This is where I want it inserted)_NAME"             
    Value "TODO"

StringInfo  
    ID "IDS_(This is where I want it inserted)_DESCRIPTION"                                   
    Value "TODO"
```

So I want the end result to look like this:

```
StringInfo  
    ID "IDS_WRAITH_CAPITALBATTLESHIP_NAME  
    Value "TODO"

StringInfo  
ID "IDS_WRAITH_CAPITALBATTLESHIP_DESCRIPTION"  
Value "TODO"
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I just confused you, I will try to be more clear in the future.

I **preferably** want a `.bat` file with the code

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is confusing. If you want to insert each string twice, you should post an example of the desired output when the replace string appear the third time. Anyway, I think this is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "twice="
< Lines2Insert.txt (
   set /P insert=
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" input.txt') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line (
         for /F %%i in ("!insert!") do set "lineMod=!line:(This is where I want it inserted)=%%i!"
         if "!line!" neq "!lineMod!" (
            if not defined twice (
               set twice=yes
            ) else (
               set "twice="
               set /P insert=
            )
         )
         echo(!lineMod!
      ) else (
         echo/
      )
   )
) > modFile.txt
move /Y modFile.txt input.txt
```

Using this file as **input.txt**:

```
StringInfo
    ID "IDS_(This is where I want it inserted)_NAME"
    Value "TODO"

StringInfo
    ID "IDS_(This is where I want it inserted)_DESCRIPTION"
    Value "TODO"

StringInfo
    ID "IDS_(This is where I want it inserted)_OTHERDATA"
    Value "TODO"
```

This is **the result**:

```
StringInfo
    ID "IDS_WRAITH_CAPITALBATTLESHIP_NAME"
    Value "TODO"

StringInfo
    ID "IDS_WRAITH_CAPITALBATTLESHIP_DESCRIPTION"
    Value "TODO"

StringInfo
    ID "IDS_WRAITH_CAPITALCARRIER_OTHERDATA"
    Value "TODO"
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Sorry I wasn't being more clear.